# Avoiding running all makefiles after running make on a target

Tags: makefile, data-science, gnu-make

I'm new to Make, and am trying to use it to automate a ml pipeline. I have defined two rules in two files: the first `Makefile` has file locations and a target to clean a dataset. The second one `Makefile.label.surv1` has a target to extract labels using a python script. Below is the code for both:

Makefile

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Survival Analysis - Churn prediction top makefile
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

# date of the snapshot to consider
SNAP_TRN := 2019-06-18
SNAP_TST := 2019-07-24

# directories
DIR_DATA := data
DIR_BUILD := build
DIR_FEATURE := $(DIR_BUILD)/feature
DIR_METRIC := $(DIR_BUILD)/metric
DIR_MODEL := $(DIR_BUILD)/model
DIR_CONFIG := configs

# data files for training and predict
DATA_TRN := $(DIR_DATA)/processed/
DATA_TST := $(DIR_DATA)/processed/

# NOS feature selection
FEATS := $(DIR_CONFIG)/featimp_churnvol.csv
# Config files
CONFIG_PANEL := $(DIR_CONFIG)/config_panel.yaml
CONFIG_INPUT := $(DIR_CONFIG)/config_inpute.yaml

# Generates a clean dataset (inputted and one hot encoded) and labels for train and test
buildDataset: $(DATA_TRN) $(DATA_TST) $(CONFIG_PANEL) $(CONFIG_INPUT) $(FEATS)
    python src/buildDataset.py --train-file $< \
                               --test-file $(word 1, $^) \
                               --config-panel $(word 2, $^) \
                               --config-input $(word 3, $^) \
                               --feats $(lastword $^)
```

Makefile.label.surv1

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# surv1: survival labels
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
include Makefile


FEATURE_NAME := surv1

GRAN := weekly
STUDY_DUR := 1
       
Y_SURV_TRN := $(DIR_DATA)/survival/$(FEATURE_NAME)_train_$(SNAP_TRN)_$(GRAN)_$(STUDY_DUR).pkl
Y_SURV_TST := $(DIR_DATA)/survival/$(FEATURE_NAME)_test_$(SNAP_TST)_$(GRAN)_$(STUDY_DUR).pkl

$(Y_SURV_TRN) $(Y_SURV_TST): $(DATA_TRN) $(DATA_TST) $(CONFIG_PANEL) $(STUDY_DUR) $(GRAN)
    python ./src/generate_surv_labels.py --train-file $< \
                                         --test-file $(word 1, $^) \
                                         --train-label-file $(Y_SURV_TRN) \
                                         --test-label-file $(Y_SURV_TST)\
                                         --config-panel $(word 2, $^) \
                                         --study-dur $(word 3, $^) \
                                         --granularity $(lastword $^)
```

So when I run `make -f Makefile.label.surv1`, it also re-runs the target `buildDataset`, which I don't want in this case. In this case I haven't made any changes to buildDataset so I don't understand why make re-runs this target... Is there anyway to prevent a target from re-running others?

Comment: Are you sure that the command you showed here is what you really entered?  Because `make Makefile.label.survival` is definitely not right.

Comment: im sorry, corrected it in the OP

Comment: Suggestions of improvement: define `buildDataset` as [phony](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets). Add another phony target (e.g., `all`) that has no recipe and depends on `$(Y_SURV_TRN) $(Y_SURV_TST)`. Declare it as the [default target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_002eDEFAULT_005fGOAL-_0028define-default-goal_0029). If `$(Y_SURV_TRN)` and `$(Y_SURV_TST)` are built by the same recipe, and you use GNU Make 4.3, declare that they are [grouped targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-grouped-targets).

Comment: just did that, thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't provide a target to build on the make command line, make will build the default target.  The default target is the *FIRST* explicit target defined in your makefile(s).

In your `Makefile.label.survival` the first thing you do before you define any other target, is `include Makefile`.  That means that if any target is defined in `Makefile`, it will be considered the first explicit target.

And, indeed, `Makefile` defines `buildDataset` and so that is the default target and if you run `make` without any specific target, that's the target that will be built.

Also, this rule is very likely not right:

```
$(Y_SURV_TRN) $(Y_SURV_TST): ...
```

I'm not sure what you're hoping this will do, but if you expect that make will interpret this to mean that one invocation of the recipe will build both these files, that's not what this syntax means.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes in that rule I was hoping to create both targets, but then realized it wasn't the correct approach.